# Lots of "bots" signing up to my site, should I be worried?

Tags: web-application, bot

I have run into this issue on my first website I pushed live.

I have a website that has been live for a couple of months. It had 30 people signed up over that period which as suddenly spiked up to 150+ in the last 3 days and counting. I've noticed every single one has a "real" sounding email address and then a random string as the display name in the same format making me suspicious they are not real. It's still happening multiple times throughout the day.

I'm confused as to what's happening here and worried that it seems so targeted. I'm unsure what they're trying to achieve and what is safe. The site is a Node server hosted on heroku & I am using environment variables there to keep all my secrets, as well as all user data being stored on mongodb, with encyption of accounts handled by passport.js so I think everything is safe if they're attempting to hack data.

Any thoughts on what could be happening and whether I should be worried? Furthermore, what steps can I take to figure out what's happening/stop this happening?

Comment: Why do you think that it's targetted? Are you aware that ***any*** service that has a "sign up" feature is bombarded with bot sign ups? There is a big difference between "signing up" and "hacking". Do you have evidence of hacking? Have you tried adding a CAPTCHA to your sign up process?

Comment: No i was not aware that this happened for all sign up features! Thats good to know! I am currently in the process of adding a CAPTCHA to the sign up process to try and stop it..

Comment: Ok, then, yeah, "welcome to the Internet". Bots scour the internet for anything to sign up to. Then they figure out what signing up does for them, if anything. Anything you put on the internet will get attacked, on average, every 39 seconds. Design for that as a reality.